# How to set width of table td width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have table cells of width 60 %, 20% and 20%, I use jquery I have added inline style as shown below. I tried setting display property to unset before it was table.

> let $cell00 = $('').appendTo($row22).css({"width":"60%"});

They don't seem to have any effect they seem to be in 33%, 33% and 33% case.

How to get the td of width 60%, 20% and 20%?

```js
function maintest () {

   table1();
   addClasses();
  }
 
 
 function table1 () {
    addClasses ();
   
    let h1 = $("<h3>").html("Borrowed Features:").prop("class","underline").appendTo("#BorrowedTable");
    let $table1 = $('<table>').attr({"id" : "borrowed"}).appendTo("#BorrowedTable");
    let $row11 = $('<tr>').appendTo($table1);
    let header1 = $('<td>').text("Feature").appendTo($row11).css({"width":"60%"});
    let header12 = $('<td>').text("Return Date").appendTo($row11).css({"width":"20%"});
    let $header22 = $('<td>').appendTo($row11).css({"width":"20%"});
    $('<button>Return All Now</button>').appendTo($header22).css({"bottom":"20px","position":"relative"});

    for( i=0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ) {
        let $row22 = $('<tr>').appendTo($table1);
        let $cell00 = $('<td>').appendTo($row22).css({"width":"50%"});  
        let $autocomplete12 = $("<input>").attr({"id" : "selector"+i+1,"class":"biscuitColorInput"}).appendTo($cell00);

        let $cell11 = $('<td>').appendTo($row22).css({"width":"20%"});  
        let $autocomplete22 = $("<input>").attr({"id" : "date"+i+1,"class":"biscuitColorInput"}).appendTo($cell11);

        let $cell22 = $('<td>').appendTo($row22).css({"width":"20%"});  
        let $autocomplete33 = $("<button> Return Now </button>").attr("id" , "returnBtns"+i+1).appendTo($cell22).css({"bottom":"20px","position":"relative"});
     
    }
   
}





function addClasses () {
    let tableRows = $('tr').addClass('tableRows');
    let tableDefn = $('td').attr({"class":"tableDefn"});
    let tableHeader = $('th').attr({"class":"tableHeader"});
    let tbodyDOM = $('tbody').attr({"class" : "tbodyDOM"});
}
```

```css
#buttonsdiv {
     height: unset !important;
     width:50%;
     position: relative;
     left :50px !important;
     bottom :0px !important;
     background-color: papayawhip !important;
  }
 
  #BorrowedTable, #BorrowableTable {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction: column;
    height:fit-content !important;

  }
 
 
    #borrowed , #borrowable {
      display: unset !important;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing :unset !important;
      margin-left:100px;
  }
 
 
  #BorrowedTable,.biscuitColorInput {
    background-color: sandybrown;
  }
 
  #BorrowableTable,.creamcolorInput,#buttonsdiv {
    background-color: papayawhip;
   
  }
 
.tableRows, .tableDefn, .tableHeader { /*added from addClasses() */
   
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      font-family: ffunit;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding-right: 50px !important;
    }
 
 
 
   button {
      height:36px;
      width:205px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: solid 1px;
      background-color:#f2a900;
      font-family: ffunit;
      font-size: 14px;
      margin-top:20px;
      margin-left: 1px;
  }


  input {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-indent: 6px;
   
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<body onload="maintest()">

   <div id="BorrowedTable"></div>
 
</body>
```

new image

[image]

Comment: The problem is because you've set `width: 250px` on the child `input` elements. As they cannot be broken to multiple lines their width forces the parent `td` to be wider. The same goes for the `button` in the last column.

Comment: Thanks  Rory McCrossan do I removed the width property from input element, I still don't see the change

Comment: Removing it would use the default width, which would still be too wide. I would suggest setting them to `100%` width. This will then fill the full `td` width

Comment: Thanks  Rory McCrossan I can see the td width getting altered, if I set 50%, 20 % and 20 % I see the changes . First seem to be 50% but second and thrid div seem to be unaltered

Comment: 60%, 40 % and 40 % doesn't seem to work, I have added an image I am trying to get this layout

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have set

```
display:flex;
```

on table. Instead don't set display on table and give it some width either in percentage or in pixels. After this if you give width in percentage to td it should work.

Comment: Hi Santhosh  , If I remove display: flex from table it just alters the whole layout

Comment: try setting display:inline-block; on td.
make sure tp apply suitable padding. i saw you have applied padding right to both row and td. I could be either one of them.